# Pipelined Table Function - behind the scenes

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

1. How does it make sense that I can access Nested Table's data after
   using Pipe Row command? Where is the data actually saved?

   I know that in pipelined functions the data is sent directly to the
   invoker client, and this reduces the dynamic memory of the process
   on the SGA. But when I've tried to access that information after pipelining, I succeeded. This suprises me because that means the data is actually saved somewhere, but not on the local SGA. So where?

   Here is an example I've made:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE collection_t IS OBJECT (
      ID NUMBER,
      NAME VARCHAR2(50));
   / 

   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE collection_nt_t IS TABLE OF  collection_t;
   /

   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_test_collection_p(rownumvar NUMBER)
     RETURN collection_nt_t
     PIPELINED
   IS
      collection_nt       collection_nt_t:= collection_nt_t();  
   BEGIN 
      FOR i IN 1..rownumvar LOOP
        collection_nt.EXTEND(1);
        collection_nt(i) := collection_t (i, 'test');
        PIPE ROW (collection_nt(i));    
      END LOOP;   
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(collection_nt(3).id);--"queries" the collection successfully!     Where is the collection being saved?   
      RETURN;
   END; 
   /

   SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_test_collection_p(100));
   ```
2. I have tried the idea of batches vs row-by-row (slow by
   slow) by using bulk collect and forall. But doesn't pipelining mean
   LOTS of context switches by itself? To return a row each time sounds
   like a bad idea. In addition, how do I choose the bulk size of pipe
   line function, if any?
3. Why by querying `"SELECT * FROM TABLE(..)"` sqlplus displays the
   data by batches of 15, and PL/SQL Developer displays batches of
   100? What does happen behind the scenes - batches of 1 row, no?

And why does all the world uses sqlplus, when you have nice IDEs like the convenient PL/SQL Developer? Even small clues from you would help me, Thanks a lot!

---

Details For 1: When I am doing the same with a regular Function table, the memory in use is something like 170MB per 1M rows. But when using the above pipeline table function, the memory is not increased. I am trying to understand what exactly is taking the memory - the fact that the collection is saved as a variable?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_test_collection(rownumvar NUMBER)  RETURN 
collection_nt_t  IS
  collection_nt       collection_nt_t:= collection_nt_t(); 
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..rownumvar LOOP
    collection_nt.EXTEND(1);
    collection_nt(i) := collection_t (i, 'test');
  END LOOP;
  RETURN collection_nt;
END;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_test_collection(1000000));--170MB of SGA delta!
SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_test_collection_p(1000000));--none. but both of them store the whole collection!
```

Comment: *when I've tried to access that information after pipelining, I succeeded.* So, how?

Comment: Accessing by the table function is obvious. But how and why does the Pipe line function itself store the collection? It should retrieve the data to the caller and forget about it (on every row). That's how it reduces memory, no? But in the example I can access ALL of the rows of the collection in the pipeline function itself (dbms output). Am I understood or should I explain more? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Well... *You* store the collection in your variable `collection_nt`, so you shouldn't be surprised that you can access it.

Comment: I am surprised why it doesn't use lots of memory. When I'm doing the same without a Pipeline function, the PGA is spending something like 170MB (when using 1M rows). Here it spends nothing. Where does the magic take place?

Comment: @René Nyffenegger - I've just edited the question to clarify the ambiguity (at the bottom of the question). Thank you!

Comment: How are you measuring the memory usage, and are you looking at both PGA and SGA? Are you populating the collection in the `_p` version to prove a point - since it isn't necessary, as you can pipe the new `_t` object directly? It would 'forget about it (on every row)' if you weren't doing that.

Comment: OK Thanks a lot @AlexPoole! It has been mine own misunderstanding that led to a memory mystery. I made a package measuring the 'total PGA inuse' in gv$pgastat. From your anwer I can understand that it might be shown on the SGA which I haven't checked yet.